# Using Superset helm chart with pre-existing postgres database

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, google-kubernetes-engine, apache-superset

I have a k8s cluster which I have already installed Apache Superset with Postgres dependency enabled. But now I want to use my own PostgresDB so I configured `values.yaml`

```
postgresql:
  ## Set to false if bringing your own PostgreSQL.
  enabled: false

# ...

supersetNode:
  connections:
    db_host: "10.0.0.0" # example IP
    db_port: "5432"
    db_user: my-db-user
    db_pass: "secret"
    db_name: superset
```

I have already tested connecting with `psql` from inside pod in cluster and it works.

But when I run install command:

```
 helm install superset ../mypath/superset/ -n superset \
    --wait --timeout=15m0s \
    --namespace superset --create-namespace \
    -f ../mypath/superset/values.yaml \
```

It just never deploys successfully, I keep getting error:

```
superset connection to server at "10.0.0.0", 
port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "my-db-user"
```

I then tried attaching debugger image to superset pod:

```
kubectl debug -n superset superset-657c7b68d6-x257b -it --image=arunvelsriram/utils
```

And then run `psql -U my-db-user -h 10.0.0.0 -d superset -p 5432` and it works so it's not a networking issue

I'm in GKE in case that makes any difference and am using a pre-existing Nginx load balancer Ingress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did couple minor changes to values.yaml and now it works:

```
postgresql:
  enabled: false

supersetNode:
  connections:
    db_host: "10.0.0.0"
    db_port: "5432"
    db_user: myuser
    db_pass: "secret"
    db_name: superset
```

seems using username without dashes made it work

Answer (score -1):

Host IP ending with 0 zero. I don't think it's quite right.